# I am unable to run classic asp application through IIS7.5

Tags: iis, asp-classic

When I am trying to run the classic asp application over iis7.5 I am getting error "The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden. The extension '.asp' may be incorrect. Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly."

Comment: Is it windows 7 built in server or you've configured it

Comment: can you give me your error number(if it gives you one)?

Comment: Here is the error details Server Error in '/Source' Application.

This type of page is not served. 
Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.asp' may be incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /Source/Search.asp
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5448; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5420

Comment: There are so many issues . You can find here similar problem http://forums.asp.net/t/1066680.aspx/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classic ASP is not enabled by default in IIS 7 and 7.5. It is easy to enable, see http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.